# Count number of non-NA values greater than 0 by group

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Here is an example of a data set `df`:

```
Name    L1     L2     L3    L4
Carl    1       NA     0     2
Carl    0       1     4     1 
Joe     3       0     3     1
Joe     2       2     1     0
```

I would like to create a function that would be able to tally up the number of values in columns L2, L3, and L4 that are greater than 0 as a function of some name. For example:

```
someFunction(Joe)
# 4
```

However, I have some `NA`s in my columns.

I have tried using `complete.cases` to remove the `NA`s but I do not want to remove the entire row. I want to use `aggregate`, however, I am not exactly sure how. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
colSums(df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or you may want a sum per person:

```
m <- rowsum((df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0) + 0, df[["Name"]], na.rm = TRUE)

#     L2 L3 L4
#Carl  1  1  2
#Joe   1  2  1
```

There is something fun here. `df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0` is a logical matrix (with `NA`):

- Although `colSums` can work with it without trouble, `rowsum` can not. So a fix is to add a `0` to this matrix to cast it to a 0-1 numerical matrix;
- when adding this `0`, we must do `(df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0) + 0` not `df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0 + 0`. The operation precedence in R means `+` is prior to `>`. Have a try on this toy example:

  ```
  5 > 4 + 0  ## FALSE
  (5 > 4) + 0  ## 1
  ```

  So we want a bracket to evaluate `>` first, then `+`.

If you want the result to be a data frame, just cast the resulting matrix into a data frame by:

```
data.frame(m)
```

---

**Follow-up**

People stop responding, because your specific question on getting a function is less interesting than getting the summary dataset.

Well, if you still take my approach, I would define such function as:

```
extract <- function (person) {
  m <- rowsum((df[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0) + 0, df[["Name"]], na.rm = TRUE)
  rowSums(m)[[person]]
  }
```

Then you can call

```
extract("Joe")
# 4
extract("Carl")
# 4
```

Note, this is obviously not the most efficient way to write such a function. Because if you only want to extract the sum for one person, there is no need to proceed all data. We can do:

```
extract2 <- function (person) {
  ## subset data
  sub <- subset(df, df$Name == person, select = c("L2", "L3", "L4"))
  ## get sum
  sum(sub > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

Then you can call

```
extract2("Joe")
# 4
extract2("Carl")
# 4
```

Answer (score 3):

With `aggregate`, you'll need to set both the `na.rm` parameter of `sum`, plus the `na.action` parameter of `aggregate` itself. After that, it's easy to add the three columns:

```
df_sums <- aggregate(. ~ Name, df, FUN = function(x) {
    sum(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
}, na.action = na.pass)

df_sums$sum_L2_L3_L4 <- with(df_sums, L1 + L2 + L3)

df_sums
##   Name L1 L2 L3 L4 sum_L2_L3_L4
## 1 Carl  1  1  1  2            4
## 2  Joe  2  1  2  1            4
```

---

or in dplyr,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(sum(. > 0, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
    mutate(sum_L2_L3_L4 = L2 + L3 + L4)

## # A tibble: 2 × 6
##     Name    L1    L2    L3    L4 sum_L2_L3_L4
##   <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int>        <int>
## 1   Carl     1     1     1     2            4
## 2    Joe     2     1     2     1            4
```

or directly,

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(sum = sum(cbind(L2, L3, L4) > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##     Name   sum
##   <fctr> <int>
## 1   Carl     4
## 2    Joe     4
```

---

or data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x){sum(x > 0, na.rm = TRUE)}), by = Name
    ][, sum_L2_L3_L4 := L2 + L3 + L4, by = Name][]

##    Name L1 L2 L3 L4 sum_L2_L3_L4
## 1: Carl  1  1  1  2            4
## 2:  Joe  2  1  2  1            4
```

or directly,

```
setDT(df)[, .(sum = sum(cbind(L2, L3, L4) > 0, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Name]

##    Name sum
## 1: Carl   4
## 2:  Joe   4
```

Comment: Thank you @alistaire. I tried using your `aggregate` function. It works well, however, it gives me a table with all of the columns summed up for each name. Is there a way to make this a part of a function so that someFunction(Joe)=4 ? Does this make sense?

Comment: Oops, misunderstood. Updated.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to be given a table as my answer, I just want the total gross sum for a name.

Comment: A list of names with a sum for each sounds like a table, no? If not, you should edit your question with exactly what your desired output looks like.

Comment: I edited my question, thank you. Im sorry for the confusion. I would just like an answer that looks something like someFunction(Joe) = 4

Comment: R is designed to be vectorized, which means you're calling that `someFunction` on all the names at once. You could write `someFunction <- function(name){sum(df[df$Name == name, paste0('L', 2:4)] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)}`, but that's decidedly less useful as data scales.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `aggregate` with `rowSums` to get the output

```
aggregate(cbind(Total=rowSums(df[3:5]>0, 
              na.rm=TRUE))~cbind(Name=df$Name), FUN = sum)
#  Name Total
#1 Carl     4
#2  Joe     4
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Name' and specifying the select column in `.SDcols`, `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), convert it to a logical vector (`>0`) and get the `sum` of the TRUE values to create the summarised 'Total' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Total = sum(unlist(.SD)>0, na.rm = TRUE)), Name, .SDcols = L2:L4]
#   Name Total
#1: Carl     4
#2:  Joe     4
```

---

Or another option is with `dplyr/tidyr`.  We `select` the columns of interest, `gather` into 'long' format, `filter` only the elements that are greater than 0, then grouped by 'Name' get the total number of rows (`n()`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    select(-L1) %>% 
    gather(Var, Val, -Name) %>% 
    filter(Val>0) %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(Total = n())
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#   Name Total
#  <chr> <int>
#1  Carl     4
#2   Joe     4
```

Answer (score 1):

With  `plyr` you could do:

```
library(plyr)

nonZeroDF = ddply(DF[,-2],"Name",.fun = function(x) 
data.frame(nonZeroObs=sum((x[,-1]) >0,na.rm=TRUE) ))

#  Name nonZeroObs
#1 Carl          4
#2  Joe          4
```